# RegExp in C# to find a "(number)" expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a description text file with content constructed in such manner:

```
Book title - (number)
```

Currently user needs to find book title, then reads the book number and looks for the appropriate file (number.txt is a file name of book).

I want to use Regexp class to extract "(number)" expression. My sample code doesn't work (returns TRUE even if "( )" don't exist:

```
Regex r = new Regex("([0-9])");
```

Could you help me to construct correct RegExp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape the parentheses:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\([0-9]\)");
```

And if `number` contains more that one digit, you should add `+`:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\([0-9]+\)");
```

Or

```
Regex r = new Regex("\\([0-9]+\\)");
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't work - even doesn't compile. Error: "unrecognized escape sequence". I also try this solution earlier. It seems like C# doesn't allow to escape brackets "()" symbols.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are only looking for a single digit, try this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("\([0-9]+\)");
```

Which searches for one or more digits in the range 0-9. Escaping the parentheses will also ensure that only numbers between the brackets are found.